# WPF ListBox Item labels from bound collection are blank

Tags: wpf, data-binding, styles

I am having some trouble with my WPF styling. I have a `ListBox` which contains a bunch of *blank* (not supposed to be blank) labels. is defined in my XAML as follows:

```
            <ListBox Height="auto" Name="ProjectsList" Width="auto" DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="3">
                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}" Foreground="Black" Height="40" Padding="7" VerticalAlignment="Center" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Name="ProjectName" />
                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=TaskCount}" Foreground="Gray" Width="25" Name="ProjectTaskCount" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

`Projects` is an `ObservableCollection` which is filled with `Project` structs (Which I defined) which are created after a database query to grab the corresponding data. I can step through the code and see that the query comes back fine, and see the structs getting filled out and added to the collection. I also know that it's populating the `ListBox` Because I can select the blank item in it and it gets highlighted. But there is no text like there should be.

The `Project` attribute `Name` is a `string` and `TaskCount` is an `int`.

Here's the `Project` Definition

```
public struct Project
{
    public Int64 Id;
    public string Name;
    public string Description;
    public bool HasDueDate;
    public DateTime DueDate;
    public Int64 UserId;
    public int TaskCount;
}
```

The question is: why does the text not show up?

Comment: can you show how you are binding you viewmodel to view? and is Project struct implements INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: No, `Project` doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChange`. I will add some more info.

Comment: please implement INPC and hope things will work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just bind to **public Properties**. i just see fields on your struct. and like the others said: implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raise it properly

Answer (score 1):

You should implement INotifyPropertyChanged to your business object. Which will directly notify the property changes to the UI using the PropertyChanged call back.. But i am not sure whether you are using this to bind the ListBox....

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/81484/A-Practical-Quick-start-Tutorial-on-MVVM-in-WPF

http://wpftutorial.net/MVVM.html